# Showing Toast in View method with ListAdapter

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-toast

I make a list view with Adapter and and I have a toggle button that i hope can showing a toast, but it didn't work...

this is my codes in AppCompactActivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStated){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStated);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);

    QuestionsListAdapter q = new QuestionsListAdapter(this, questions, picture);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(q);

}
```

And this is getView function in my ListAdapter

```
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictures_question, null,true);

    ImageView pic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.q_picture);
    question = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_q_question);
    btnPlayer = (ToggleButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_q_player);

    question.setText(questions[position]);
    pic.setImageResource(picture[position]);

    teks  = question.getText().toString();

    btnPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnPlayer.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), teks + " ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else if (!btnPlayer.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), teks + " OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    });

    return rowView;

};
```

So, I hope someone can resolve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add **`show()`** method in your **`Toast`**

> **`show()`**
>
> `void show ()`
> You can display the toast notification with `show()`

Try this

```
 btnPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnPlayer.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), teks + " ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (!btnPlayer.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), teks + " OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: oh man thank you, but my second button can not showing the array in index 1, but showing array in index 2

Comment: exactly my toggle button did not match with my array list

Comment: @user8322851 from where you are getting `questions[position]`

Comment: how to call it? combine with the toggle button

Comment: @user8322851 can you explain more about it

Comment: @user8322851 you need to pass position

Comment: do you have some references to pass the position?

Comment: where is your listview explain more about your question @user8322851

Answer (score 0):

full answer. Sorry for my bad english.

```
   public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictures_question, null,true);

    ImageView pic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.q_picture);
    question = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_q_question);
    btnPlayer = (ToggleButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_q_player);
    question.setText(questions[position]);
    pic.setImageResource(picture[position]);
    btnPlayer.setTag(position);

    btnPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int positionItem = (int) v.getTag();
            if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), questions[positionItem] + " ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), questions[positionItem] + " OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return rowView;

};
```